# Combining Two Incongruent tables (Crystal Reports)

Tags: mysql, date, crystal-reports

I'm trying to create a productivity report; however, do to the limitations of our tables I'm having a very tough time.

The report looks at the amount of time the employee did something divided by their available time and it gets compared a set number, that can sometimes vary for the employee. Employees work varying schedules. So for any given week or month the available time for two different employees can be different. I can't use a set available time number for everyone.

My two main sources of information are table of employee activity based on service dates and a table of employee availability to compare it against. The only thing these tables have in common is the employee id number.

The service dates table has an incomplete range of date for each employee. I can tell crystal to look for dates between a range but I can't see what an employee did on dates that didn't have a service.

My availability table only records the date availability ended and started and the date it was entered. After that it only shows that the employee is available on Monday at a set time, on a Tuesday, etc. The times don't matter to me, I just need the days (which I multiply by 7 to get hours).

So far I've created two reports.

The first mainly uses the employee activity table. With it I can calculate the number of working days (our company has a slightly different holiday schedule which includes some half days) for any given period of time using a formula and I'm, oddly enough able to calculate the amount of vacation sick/time an employee has off.

For the second I use the availability table combined with an sql command to create a whole date range. I then convert the dates from the date range to DAYSOFWEEK. Then I count each day code from the availability code on the condition that the code match the day of the week. And I can also limit the date range to anything I want. I haven't yet but I'm sure I can also determine company workings days as well.

Both reports work. In the one report I can see the hours worked in combination with the vacation/sick time as well as working days and in the other I can see anyone's available hours for a given period of time not counting holidays (which could be factored in) and vacation/sick time (which as of this moment I have no way of getting in this report.

How do i combine these two working reports into one working report? I've tried doing a subreport or using the sql command to create dates in combination with staff activity table none has worked for me so far. Not with this report but I've also tried creating a separate spreadsheet of dates to use as a table which works just fine with crystal reports but the software we run the reports through does not like it.

A really condensed version of what I want:

Report 1 - staff activity
Report 2 - staff availability

Employee 1

Worked 83 Hours was available 23 days (x 7) - 1.5 holidays + 2 sick days

83  / (23*7  - 1.5  - 2 )

83 **(R1)** / (23*7 **(R2)** - 1.5 **(R1 OR R2)** - 2 **(R1)**)

Employee 2

Worked 79 Hours was available 22 days (x 7) - 1.5 holidays + 1 sick days

79 / (22*7  - 1.5  - 1 )

79 **(R1)** / (22*7 **(R2)** - 1.5 **(R1 OR R2)** - 1 **(R1)**)

I hope this all makes sense

Thanks

Comment: can you summarize in few lines your exact requirement?

Comment: I need to take the number of hours worked (which can vary from employee to employee) and divide that by the total hours available which is the number of working days (which can vary employee to employee) minus the number of staff holidays and paid vacation sick time. I have two tables to glean this information from. One table gives me dates worked and vacation/sick time and the other gives me dates available based on days of the week not actual calendar days. In neither table (or any table) are holidays being tracked.

Comment: ok looks like you are not sure how to calculate holidays since those are not available in database.... I can suggest 2 ways if you can manipulate database then create a table and insert the records for the days where you have holidays, in other case create an array of the month and holidays and manipulate in report... let me know if I understood correctly and which option you are feasible will try to explain more in answer

Comment: I ran an sql command to get a set of dates. It works with the table featuring the availability but I'm having trouble getting it to work with the dates worked table